# How to map loop an object Array with nested object Arrays?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some data I want to render that looks like this:
[image]

How can I map loop the entire CarParts array and then map loop the nested tyres array inside it and still maintain their respective index order?

```
{CarParts.map((parts, index) => (
  <div key={index}>
    {parts.system && (
      <div className="bg-red-500">
        <p>{parts.system}</p>
      </div>
    )}

    {parts.tyres && (
      <>
        {parts.tyres.map((tyre, index) => (
          <div className="bg-green-500" key={index}>
            <p>Tyre: {tyre}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </>
    )}
```

Output in browser should look like this:

System: Engine

Tyre: Bridgestone

Tyre: Michelin

Tyre: Goodyear

System: Exhaust Pipe

Comment: Where in your code did you attempt to output those horizontal lines?

Comment: @trincot Nowhere, I did it here just to divide the divs, I wanted to change colors but it's not possible. I've removed them now since it's confusing.

Comment: Please post code, error messages, markup, **data structures**, and other textual information **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: *"`key={index}`"* Beware that this is an antipattern unless the data is static, details [in this blog post](https://robinpokorny.com/blog/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern/) and [the React documentation linking to it](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{carParts.map((parts) => {
                              return (
                                 <div>
                                    {!Array.isArray(parts) && (
                                       <div>System :{parts.system}</div>
                                    )}
                                    {Array.isArray(parts) && (
                                       <div>
                                          {parts.map((tyre) => {
                                             return (
                                                <div>Tyre: {tyre.tyres}</div>
                                             )
                                          })}
                                       </div>
                                    )}
                                 </div>
                              )
                           })}
```

check element is array, then map again.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to what your code suggests, your object array does not have objects with a `tyres` property that is an array. Instead, your array seems to either have single-property objects **or** arrays with such objects.

So if your intention is to just output the objects without regard of whether they exist at the first or second level of arrays, then just flatten the array first.

The basic structure of your code then becomes:

```
{CarParts.flat().map(part => (
    <div>
      <p>{Object.entries(part)[0].join(": ")}</p>
    </div>
))}
```

Again, this assumes that the actual plain objects each have only one property and value, as is suggested by the image of the data structure.